# Alternative to Chromedriver

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have made several scripts for my work as an Accountant that automates many of our daily tasks like downloading some pdfs and mailing them. 
This scripts are made with Ruby, Watir and chromedriver. 
The main problem that i thought i was going to have is the change in the websites but that was not as problematic as the updates in chrome.

Every time there was a chrome update they changed the flags so i was unable to download pdfs i had to find the appropriate flags and it was fraustrating.

I manage to solve the above problem by creating a new [profile](https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles) of chrome for every script then changing the settings and manually saved them.

But there are at least 50 scripts and everyone needs a different setting for the chromedriver, it starts to get on my nerves.

Except that, I deployed an Ubuntu machine so everything will be more automated and not starting manually the script from my windows machine. Even in there the chromium keeps getting the same changes and eventually when updated it breaks everything.

I thought that the phantomjs could be good but I see that it is dead.

So the main question is do you know any driver that I can use, that hasn't got all the cr@p that the chrome does?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just not update your gems? If you use bundler it makes a Gemfile.lock so you will get the same versions next time. Phantomjs is deprecated but it still works so that might be a good solution too.

Comment: We use Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox and just configured Firefox to stop automatic updates. Didn't touch it for more than a year now and works great (both windows and ubuntu)

Comment: @pguardiario the problem is not with the gems. Its with the autoupdate of chrome.

Comment: @VitaliMargolin I really want to get out of this mess. The problem is not only with the updates but with the flags and switches. There are nowhere to be found. I would rather have a dead-simple browser.

Comment: @beieronym - you can also download a standalone chromium and set the path to that in selenium.

Comment: @pguardiario yes this is what i am doing. I am making a custom profile for its script. But i would like the browser to be manipulated by the script and not by the settings that i have setup in it.

Comment: If you're talking about userDataDir, that's not where you set the path to chromium. FTR  chromium has the same revision numbers as chromedriver because they get released together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone dealing with Watir and Chromedriver or Chrome in general.
It seems that the pref directory_upgrade must be set in order for the chromedriver to download the file.
Also to the ones using watir.
In the latest versions this

```
   prefs = {
  download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    default_directory: path,
  },
   plugins: {
    always_open_pdf_externally: true
  },
}
```

must be modified like this

```
    prefs = {
  download: {
    "prompt_for_download" => false,
    "directory_upgrade"   => true,
    "default_directory" => path,
  },
   plugins: {
    "always_open_pdf_externally" => true
  },
}
```